# Increasing MDB'S instances

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I am using jboss 5.1.x 
I am trying to increase my mdb's instances. 
but no success.

some code:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = 
{ @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue =  
"javax.jms.Queue"), 
 @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = 
 Constants.QUEUE_LOOKUP), 
 @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "50") 
} 

) 

public class ECMSDispatcherMdb implements MessageListener 
  { 
      ... 
   }
```

now when I look at the Console Admin, under the Queues\MyQueue tree:

```
 Consumer Count 1 The number of consumers on the queue 
 Message Count 0 The number of messages in the queue
```

- the Consumer Count, keep being only 1.

any idea what is wrong? or what haven't I configured right?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDBs are processed by making one instance and invoking its `onMessage(..)` method. So why do you need more instances?

Comment: What if MDB uses instance variable? Being called from 2 separate threads it might cause conflict.

Comment: don't use instance variables :)

Comment: I wanted to have more then one instance of MDB in my system to work parallel on my JMS Que

Comment: Bozho, you are right. I personally do not use them, but it is not forbidden by spec.

Comment: Rayman, as Bozho said, you actually do not need several instances to process several messages simultaneously. Just try test I suggested, see that your messages are processed in parallel, relax and go on!

Comment: Thanks, Although this is weird, that it shows the number of consumers as "1". in Weblogic  the number of consumers is exactly the number of instances which listens to the JMS que.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. Everything is fine. You do not need more than one instance of your MDB when they have nothing to do (0 messages in queue).

If you wish to see several instances I believe you have to perform some kind of load test to force server to create additional instances. Or you can do it easier. Add Thread.sleep(60000) to your MDB. Now push 2 messages to your queue.

In this case the processing of each message will take 1 min, so I guess server will have to process them simultaneously that probably will force it to create additional instance.

Comment: Then why it shows in the console only 1  as number of consumers?